# Can I add chapter metadata to a video file using only the FFmpeg CLI?

Tags: ffmpeg, metadata, video-encoding, command-line-arguments, chapters

I've recently gotten into using FFmpeg and was wondering if there was a way of adding chapter markers entirely through the command line interface?

I have had success with first writing out a metadata text file, then manually editing it and then splicing it together with the original video file into a new file.  This is a little bit of a drag though and it would be much more preferable if it could be done entirely through some extra flag or through a single command such as...

```
ffmpeg -i videoname.mp4 -add_chptr START=00:00:00.000 title:"video title"
```

Does anyone know if something like this exists? I could not find something about it in the help page but the documentation seems to be almost endless to me.

Comment: Not available..

Comment: Alright, it was worth a try. Thank you for clarifying!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same need. Apparently there is no easy or any way to add chapters from a chapter file with FFmpeg. For MKV, the tool to use is mkvpropedit. It edits the header only, in seconds. For automatic processing, the media file and the chapter file need the same name and location. You need the [MKVToolNix](http://mkvtoolnix.download/windows/releases/)

suite [(Windows XP).](http://mkvtoolnix.download/windows/releases/29.0.0/mkvtoolnix-32-bit-29.0.0.7z)

```
set MKVToolNix=
set file=
FOR %%A IN ("%file%") do "%MKVToolNix%mkvpropedit" -c "%%~pnA" %%A&pause
```

Comment: It is possible to add chapter to a file using ffmpeg. See some minimal working examples in this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76692220/whats-the-purpose-of-the-end-field-in-files-containing-metadata-for-ffmpeg?noredirect=1#comment135213013_76692220